# Why using Asyncio is not reducing the overall execution time in Python and run functions concurrently?

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am trying to run a piece of code using asyncio and reduce the time execution of the whole code. Below is my code which is taking around 6 seconds to fully execute itself

**Normal function calls- (approach 1)**

```
from time import time, sleep
import asyncio


def find_div(range_, divide_by):
    lis_ = []
    for i in range(range_):
        if i % divide_by == 0:
            lis_.append(i)
        
    print("found numbers for range {}, divided by {}".format(range_, divide_by))
    return lis_

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time()
    find_div(50800000, 341313)
    find_div(10005200, 32110)
    find_div(50000340, 31238)
    print(time()-start)
```

The output of the above code is just the total execution time which is **6 secs**.

**Multithreaded Approach- (approach 2)**
Used multithreading in this, but surprisingly the time increased

```
from time import time, sleep
import asyncio
import threading


def find_div(range_, divide_by):
    lis_ = []
    for i in range(range_):
        if i % divide_by == 0:
            lis_.append(i)
        
    print("found numbers for range {}, divided by {}".format(range_, divide_by))
    return lis_

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=find_div, args=(50800000, 341313)) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=find_div, args=(10005200, 32110)) 
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=find_div, args=(50000340, 31238)) 
  
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 
    t3.start()

    t1.join() 
    t2.join() 
    t3.join()
    print(time()-start)
```

The output of the above code is **12 secs**.

**Multiprocessing approach- (approach 3)**

```
from time import time, sleep
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Pool

def multi_run_wrapper(args):
   return find_div(*args)

def find_div(range_, divide_by):
    lis_ = []
    for i in range(range_):
        if i % divide_by == 0:
            lis_.append(i)
        
    print("found numbers for range {}, divided by {}".format(range_, divide_by))
    return lis_

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time()
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.map(multi_run_wrapper,[(50800000, 341313),(10005200, 32110),(50000340, 31238)])
    
    
    print(time()-start)
```

The output of the multiprocessing code is **3 secs** which is better than the normal function call approach.

**Asyncio Approach- (approach 4)**

```
from time import time, sleep

import asyncio

async def find_div(range_, divide_by):
    lis_ = []
    for i in range(range_):
        if i % divide_by == 0:
            lis_.append(i)
        
    print("found numbers for range {}, divided by {}".format(range_, divide_by))
    return lis_


async def task():

    tasks = [find_div(50800000, 341313),find_div(10005200, 32110),find_div(50000340, 31238)]
    result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time()
    asyncio.run(task())
    print(time()-start)
```

The above code is also taking around **6 seconds** which is the same as the normal execution function call that is the **Approach 1**.

**Problem-**
Why is my Asyncio approach not working as expected and reducing the overall time?
 What is wrong in the code?

Comment: I assume this is just example code? Because there is a MUCH more efficient way to get a list of all multiples of a number than checking modulo for each number in the range

Comment: Your "async" functions don't await anything, so they don't even attempt to switch execution, they are just executed as normal sync code. If you add something like `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in the loop, they will start yielding and execute concurrently. Note that you won't get speedup that way, it might even turn out that async is the slowest of all tested variants. As explained in the answer, this is because async execution is designed for waiting in parallel, not for doing things in parallel, and your code is clearly CPU-bound.

Comment: If you want to use asyncio for other things in your program (like, say, network communication), but have CPU-bound code which should execute on multiple cores, you can combine multiprocessing and asyncio using [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools).

Comment: MaxNoe, yes this is just a sample/example code. user4815162342, thanks this link seems useful, I'll check this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have code that exclusively uses the CPU.
Code like this cannot be sped up using async.

Async shines when you have tasks that are waiting on something not CPU related, e.g.  a network request or reading from disk. This is generally true for all languages.

In python, also the thread based approach will not help you, as this still restricts you to a single core and not true parallel execution. This is due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). The overhead of starting and switching between threads makes it slower than the simple version.
In this regard,  threads are similar to async in python,  it only helps if the time you are waiting is not spend mainly on the CPU or if you are calling code that's not bound by the GIL, e.g. c extensions.

Using `multiprocessing` really uses multiple cpu cores, so it is faster than the normal solution.

Comment: So, If I have a database connection that might be an async library and executing some SQL, those things can be added in an Async fashion right? Could you guide me to a good resource for a pymssql async kind of functionality?

Comment: @johnmich you can use aiomysql which is an async library for database.

Answer (score 0):

```
asyncio def run(time):
     await asyncio.sleep(time)
```

This code takes 1 min 40 seconds

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

task=[]
for i in range(10):
    await run(10)  

now1=datetime.now()
print(now1-now)
```

OPTIMIZED USING async-->

THis takes 10 seconds only

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

task=[]
for i in range(10):
    task.append(asyncio.create_task(run(10)))
await asyncio.gather(*task)   

now1=datetime.now()
print(now1-now)
```